# How to run a single .mod file and lots of .dat files using CPLEX and java?

Tags: java, cplex

I am new to CPLEX and Java.

I have a single .mod file and a huge number of .dat files (Eg. loads1_2.dat , loads1_3.dat .... and so on till loads796_796.dat). I would like to determine whether there exists a solution after compiling the .mod file and loadsi_j.dat file (taken one at a time) (i.e. 1 if there exists a solution if I compile say loads34_56.dat and the .mod file , else 0).

Is there any function through IBM ILOG OPL or java that can help me solve this?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following main script in IBM ILOG OPL :

```
    main{

var src = new IloOplModelSource("loads1.mod");
var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(src);


var iteration=1;  

    while(iteration<=796){
        var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
        var filename="loads1_"+iteration;
        var data = new IloOplDataSource(filename+".dat");
        opl.addDataSource(data);
        var details=opl.dataElements;
        opl.generate();
        if(cplex.solve()){
            writeln(filename+"->"+1);
        }
        else{
            writeln(filename+"->"+0);
        }
        iteration++
    }
}
```